# When I present my UIImagePickerController, nothing comes up

Tags: ios, swift

What I'm trying to do is present an alert, where the user eaither presess get photo from camera, or photolibrary. However, when I press library, the UIImagePickerViewController doesn't present. I am adding UIAlert actions to the ALert, and the handler of which I am passing in is as a function which presents the ImagePicker controller. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has to do with how I am presenting the ImagePickerViewController, but I'm not sure. I read the apple docs and they said that a popover is the only style to present it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignupViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePic: UIButton!

    //When button is pressed, alert will pop up

    @IBAction func bringUpAlert(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
            func showCamera(){
                let camera = UIImagePickerController()
                UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
                camera.delegate = self
                camera.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
            func showLibrary(){
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
                    let library = UIImagePickerController()
                    library.delegate = self
                    library.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    library.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
                    self.present(library, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                func imagePickerController(_picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: [String:Any]) {
                    let selectedImage = didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
                    self.ProfilePic.setImage(selectedImage, for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Customizing Profile Pic View
        ProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = ProfilePic.frame.size.width / 2
        ProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
        ProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 3
        ProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The image picker is never shown. In the action alert, the function `showCamera` is never called.

The solution is to remove the function.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
    let camera = UIImagePickerController()
    UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
    camera.delegate = self
    camera.sourceType = .camera
    self.present(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```

Or, move the `showCamera` function declaration outside and call it from the alert action.

```
func showCamera(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        let camera = UIImagePickerController()
        camera.delegate = self
        camera.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
    showCamera()
}))
```

The same is needed of the embedded `showLibrary` function. And the image picker delegate method also needs to be moved to the top-level of the class.

Final class:

```
class SignupViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePic: UIButton!

    //When button is pressed, alert will pop up

    @IBAction func bringUpAlert(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
            self.showCamera()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
            self.showLibrary()
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showCamera(){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let camera = UIImagePickerController()
            camera.delegate = self
            camera.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func showLibrary(){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let library = UIImagePickerController()
            library.delegate = self
            library.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            library.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
            self.present(library, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: [String:Any]) {
        let selectedImage = didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.ProfilePic.setImage(selectedImage, for: .normal)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Customizing Profile Pic View
        ProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = ProfilePic.frame.size.width / 2
        ProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
        ProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 3
        ProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)` -- Although that precisely follows the directions in the docs, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @7stud Thanks. Updated. That was blind copy and paste of the original code.

Comment: @maddy, Yes, I know.

Comment: Glad to help. As a new user I'd like to remind you that you can indicate that you question has been resolved by click the checkmark to the left of whatever answer may have best answered your question. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1:**

```
func doStuff(x: Int, handler: (Int) -> Void) {
        handler(x)
}

doStuff(x: 3) {val in
    print(val)
}

--output:--
3
```

**Example 2:**

```
func doStuff(x: Int, handler: (Int) -> Void) {
        handler(x)
}

doStuff(x: 3) {val in
    func calc(a: Int, b: Int) {
        print(a + b)
    }
}

--output:--
<Nothing>
```

iOS programming isn't really for beginning programmers--it's hard for experienced programmers.